# Changing audio input source with AVAudioSession causes crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I am developing an iOS app that leverages speech-to-text in order to receive audio input from the user. However, as I was testing multiple real-life scenarios, my app was crashing every time I connected an external bluetooth headset to my phone. I noticed that the crash occurs when installing a tap on an `inputNode` in the `AVAudioEngine` object.

```
func configureAudioTap() {

    let audioEngine = self.audioEngine

    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    let inputNodeFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

    audioEngine.inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputNodeFormat, block: { [unowned self] buffer, time in
        self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
    })

}
```

In the console, I get the following error

```
exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'
```

When debugging, I noticed that my bluetooth headset and the built-in microphone have different sample rates. I also went through the Audio Session Programming Guide documentation, particularly the [Responding to Route Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioHardwareRouteChanges/HandlingAudioHardwareRouteChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH5-SW1) section, yet in vain.

Any feedback would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. I am also facing a similar issue. Were you able to resolve this? And another question, were you able to reproduce this issue with every Bluetooth headset, if no, which headset are you using? That might help me relate better.

Comment: Hello @IndusWarrior, I still haven't resolved this issue. It is still occurring when switching audio sources only *while* recording. I am using AirPods if that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. Yes it helps, in my case as well the main culprit is Airpods, and I was not able to successfully reproduce with the other Bluetooth headset.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
let inputNodeFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
```

to this:

```
let inputNodeFormat = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
```

and let us know if it crashes.

I have some similar issues but not everytime.

Comment: Hello @Deryck, I have previously tried this solution. However, it doesn't solve the entirety of the problem because when the audio session is actively running and a change of input device occurs, then a crash still occurs. It only solves the case where a _new_ recording is initiated with a different input device.

Comment: I agree, but you should pause any audio input/output when session changes and start it again. What category are you using? With what options?

Comment: I am using the `.playAndRecord` category mate.

Comment: Thanks worked for me. Still, needed to untap the node in the notification AVAudioEngineConfigurationChange or AVAudioSessionRouteChange.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes

Answer (score 3):

You need a mixer node in between. The mixer will handle input source changes without crashing the app. Your code would look like this then:

```
func configureAudioTap() {
  let audioEngine = self.audioEngine

  let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
  let inputNodeFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
  let mixerNode = AVAudioMixerNode()
  audioEngine.attach(mixerNode)
  audioEngine.connect(inputNode, to: mixerNode, format: nil)

  mixerNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputNodeFormat, block: { [unowned self] buffer, time in
    self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
  })
}
```